# why isnt my animation rotating fully?

Tags: html, css, animation

Hi I'm using @webkit in css to animate shapes that i have, i want the shapes all to rotate fully to their original position around a centre, i tried rotating the shapes around the z axis. I wrote a script which i thought worked but it turns out that the first shape moves to its first position **(all shapes will transform to different position before returning to their original place)** then just replays the animation again, so their is just a loop of the first position only. How would i change the script to be able to rotate fully.

```css
#catogories-1 {
  width: 133px;
  position:fixed;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 45%;
  z-index: 6;
  -webkit-animation: catogories-1 1.5s linear infinite;
}

#catogories-2 {
  width: 133px;
  position:fixed;
  left: 55%;
  right: 45%;
  top: 37%;
  z-index: 4;
  -webkit-animation: catogories-2 1.5s linear infinite;
}

#catogories-3 {
  width: 133px;
  position:fixed;
  left: 45%;
  right: 55%;
  top: 34%;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: catogories-3 1.5s linear infinite;
}



#catogories-4 {
  width: 133px;
  position:fixed;
  left: 35%;
  right: 65%;
  top: 37%;
  z-index: 4;
  -webkit-animation: catogories-4 1.5s linear infinite;
}

#catogories-5 {
  width: 133px;
  position:fixed;
  left: 40%;
  right: 60%;
  top: 46%;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-animation: catogories-5 1.5s linear infinite;
}



@-webkit-keyframes catogories-1 {
  from {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 6;}
  to {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 55%;
    right: 45%;
    top: 37%;
    z-index: 4;
  }
}





@keyframes catogories-1 {
  from {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 6;}
  to {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 55%;
    right: 45%;
    top: 37%;
    z-index: 4;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes catogories-2 {
  from {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 55%;
    right: 45%;
    top: 37%;
    z-index: 4;}
  to {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 45%;
    right: 55%;
    top: 34%;
    z-index: 3;}
}

@keyframes catogories-2 {
  from {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 55%;
    right: 45%;
    top: 37%;
    z-index: 4;}
  to {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 45%;
    right: 55%;
    top: 34%;
    z-index: 3;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes catogories-3 {
  from {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 45%;
    right: 55%;
    top: 34%;
    z-index: 3;}
  to {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 35%;
    right: 65%;
    top: 37%;
    z-index: 4;}
}

@keyframes catogories-3 {
  from {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 45%;
    right: 55%;
    top: 34%;
    z-index: 3;}
  to {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 35%;
    right: 65%;
    top: 37%;
    z-index: 4;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes catogories-4 {
  from {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 35%;
    right: 65%;
    top: 37%;
    z-index: 4;}
  to { width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 40%;
    right: 60%;
    top: 46%;
    z-index: 5;}
}

@keyframes catogories-4 {
  from {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 35%;
    right: 65%;
    top: 37%;
    z-index: 4;}
  to { width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 40%;
    right: 60%;
    top: 46%;
    z-index: 5;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes catogories-5 {
  from {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 40%;
    right: 60%;
    top: 46%;
    z-index: 5;}
  to {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 6;}
}

@keyframes catogories-5 {
  from {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 40%;
    right: 60%;
    top: 46%;
    z-index: 5;}
  to {width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 1.5;}
}
```

```html
<div class="catogories">

  <div id="catogories-1">

    <img src="images/Rectangle-1.png">



  </div>

  <div id="catogories-2">

    <img src="images/Rectangle-1-copy.png">


  </div>

  <div id="catogories-3">

    <img src="images/Rectangle-1-copy-2.png">



  </div>

  <div id="catogories-4">

    <img src="images/Rectangle-1-copy-3.png">



  </div>

  <div id="catogories-5">

    <img src="images/Rectangle-1-copy-4.png">


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hover on the box -- it rotates 360 degrees with a transform origin at the center -- https://jsfiddle.net/5ukfqw34/

Answer (score 0):

Your current animation moves the images in a straigt line that more or less follows a part of an ellipse. Are you trying to make a full circular movement?

I've been experimenting once with a pure CSS ferris wheel. Although I never finished it, you may have a look to see how the circular animation is done:

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/u9d8aha3/1/

The key is in the animation, which looks like:

```
@keyframes spin { 100% { -transform: rotate(360deg); } }
```

In other words, use a rotate animation for the element. If you rotate a wrapper, everything in it will rotate with it. But you can rotate the items themselves in the other direction, so they will stay upright:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* Both the wrapper and the item have the same animation */
.wrapper,
.item
{
  -webkit-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
}

/* But the item animation is reversed compared to the wrapper, so it stays 
   upright. In this case, the direction of the wrapper is reversed, so it 
   turns counter-clockwise. The item rotates in its normal, clockwise 
   direction. */
.wrapper {
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    X
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: the thing is that i want to rotate in the z axis like shown in the code snipet of my code, where as yours is in  the x and y axis.